# How to access the data's(search,objects) returned by the getInputMethod on Map Method of Map Reduce Script in Netsuite

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, return, netsuite, suitescript

In getInputData() of My Map Reduce Script , I  created search on Invoice Record , created search on the custom record called contract and stored the results in one object and also i have created another search on the custom record called formula and stored the results in one object finally i returning the invoice search results, contract object , formula object.

I now that what are all the data's returned on the getInputData Method is accessed on the Map Method Using Context Object.

**I'm getting data  of the Invoice Search Results on the Map Method Using JSON.PARSE(Context.Value); How to get the Data of Contract Object and Formula Object on the Map Method.**

**CODE:**

```
var  contractRecords = {};
 var Formulas = {};
 define(['N/error', 'N/record', 'N/search', 'N/log', 'N/task', 'N/runtime', 'N/email'],
 function(error, record, search, log, task, runtime, email) {
 function getInputData() {
                try{
                log.debug("Get Input", "Initiated");
                //Invoice Search
                var invoiceSearch = search.load({
                    id: 'customsearch_invoice_search'
                });

                log.debug("invoiceSearch:", invoiceSearch);
                log.debug("GetInputData", "Completed");
                //Storing values on Contract Object by Creating Search on Contract Record
                contractRecords = loadContractRecords();
                log.debug("contractRecords:",contractRecords);
                  //Storing values on Formula Object by Creating Search on Formula Record
                Formulas = loadFormulas();
                log.debug("Formulas:",Formulas);

                return [invoiceSearch,contractRecords,Formulas];
                }catch(exception){
                    log.debug("GetInputDate Error Message:",exception);
                }
            }

             function map(context) {
                try{
                //Getting Search Results of Invoice
                var searchResult = JSON.parse(context.value);
                log.debug("searchResult:", searchResult);
                var invoiceId = searchResult.id;
                var item = searchResult.values.item.value;
                var lineId = searchResult.values.line;
                var lineUniqueKey = searchResult.values.lineuniquekey.value;
                var invoice_amt = searchResult.values.amount;

                }catch(exception){
                  log.debug("Map Error Message:",exception);
                }
                }
                  function reduce(context) {

                  log.debug("Reduce:", "Initiated");
                 }



               function summarize(summary) {
                   log.debug("summarize", "Initiated");

                  log.debug("summarize", "Completed");
               }
                 return {
                getInputData: getInputData,
                map: map,
                reduce: reduce,
                summarize: summarize
            };

        });
```

The contractRecords ,Formulas Objects are global, SO I have assigned the objects with the methods returning objects and then i have accessed the global variables on Map() Method but it returning empty values in GetInputData() Method the Same Object is Having Values. So I returned the Contract and Formula Objects along with Invoice Search results on the Return Statement of GetInputData() Method but didn't able get values of contract and formula object on the Map() method.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return of the GetInputData() Method should be one of four value types (Array | Object | search.Search | mapReduce.ObjectRef).  The latter two search.Search and mapReduce.ObjectRef both have special handling.  Each of the results of the ran search will be sent to the MAP stage.

From your example, you are returning an Array (containing three slots); which would spawn three different Map stage processes.  Each of the three Map stage processes would contain the data of only the slot (invoiceSearch, contractRecords, Formulas) from the return of GetInputData().

Do you need the data from both contractRecords and Formulas as well as invoiceSearch individual results during the Map stage?

Comment: Yes , i need the data from Contract Records, Formulas Record values and Invoice Search Results on the Map Stage.

Comment: The Map Stage runs an instance per each result in the array returned by the GetInputData() stage.  The purpose of the map stage is to organize the data returned in the previous step (GetInputData).  If you need the results of all three results at the same time; you should do that processing in the GetInputData Stage.  Once you have determined a single unit of data, you add them to an array returned by GetInputData.  This will allow you to map common data elements together to be process together.